# Replacing 12:00 am/pm with midnight/noon

Tags: views, theming, datetime

I need to accomplish the following: display 'MN' or 'NN' if the time is 00:00 or 12:00 respectively in places such as the created time on nodes and in Views dropdowns provide the option for MN/NN/AM/PM instead of just AM/PM. I'm ok with just theming this wherever possible but I do need a site wide solution. Since the code will be used on sites residing in multiple Drupal versions, it needs to be as version generic as is reasonable (maybe one for D6 and another for D7/D8)

I've had the thought that one broad solution was to create a module that replaces the format_date function in common.inc with one that replaces the am/pm string where needed in the output. Something like this not-ready-for-primetime code changed from format_date in common.inc (D6) to a new function, say "function reformatted_date" and identical to format_date except this:

```
 if (strpos('AaDlM', $c) !== FALSE) {
  $date .= t(gmdate($c, $timestamp), array(), $langcode);
    $v = $c;
        if (strpos('Aa', $v) !== FALSE) {
        if(($v = ('A'||'a') && $date('h')==12 && $date('m')==00) {
            $c = str_ireplace('AM',' NN',$c);
            } elseif ($v = ('A'||'a') && date('h')==00 && date('m')==00 {
            $c = str_ireplace('PM',' MN',$c);
            } else { 
            $c = $v;  
            }
        }
  } etc.
```

While I am pretty sure the above code won't work as it is for a variety of reasons, logic like that would this let me call this function in a template or wherever I need it instead of format_date. It is what the end user sees here that matters to me not what is stored at the database level which can and should continue to be consistent with what PHP and Drupal do. I also want to avoid hacking modules/core.

If someone can help me get the code right or provide a better, alternate solution it would be appreciated.